# custom post type by author - wp job manager

Tags: custom-post-types, php, file-manager

Hy, I am working with wp job manager, and I would like to list job applications by user, under ultimate member tabs. I have tried using this code, but it shows me all applications

```
function custom_shortcode() {

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'job_application',
 'author'=>$author_id,  );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
}
add_shortcode( 'query_my_posts', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Also i have tried this method https://suiteplugins.com/how-to-change-the-post-type-on-ultimate-member-posts-tab/

But no luck, any help?

Comment: You would be better to use WP Job Manager's help streams. [WPSE isn't intended for third-party plugin support](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That said, you probably need to define `$author_id` somewhere -- as your code stands, I'd wager it's undefined. I'm assuming you want it set to something like [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, you are going to want to add an argument to your shortcode to set a specific author_id. Once you have that you can then perform your query.

I have not tested, but the following code should put you on the track. The shortcode would be [query_my_posts author_id="#"]

```
function custom_shortcode() {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'author_id' => '',
    ), $atts);

    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'job_application',
        'author'=> $atts['author_id'],  
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
}
add_shortcode( 'query_my_posts', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Yes , but this needs me to enter user ID every time in the shortcode, any way I used get current user ID to define author, and now it work, Thanks guys